# Disable error message in Hibernate/JPA annotaion

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I'am using Hibernate / JPA as my ORM, when i use @Email and @Patern in the same field, i got two error messages.

How can i disable one of the error messages and get just one error message displayed?

**Edit :** 
My code is below

```
@Email
@Pattern(regexp="Regular expression", message = "Not a valid format!")
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
@Documented
public @interface ExtendedEmailValidator {

    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why use both validation if you dont want

Comment: If you already annotated the field with `@Email`, why do you need `@Pattern`?

Comment: if your email pattern differs from default `@Email`, so just remove `@Email` and put your own `@Pattern`

Comment: FWIW This is Bean Validation API *not* JPA API

Comment: Because i want to benefit from Hibernate email default control and control some format rules witch Hibernate does not control.

Comment: @NeilStockton : Thank you Neil for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, i removed `@Email` and fix the problem.